# Why couldn't xcode load my NIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When running a program in XCode I received the following error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/646F9805-AC4E-40A8-BC62-75B92339DCDC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D6C27367-F61B-4CAC-BB9E-1D48227CE629/WhatsNap.app> (loaded)' with name 'DisplayWarningViewController''`

I am running the following lines of code and it gets an exception at the last line. I'm not sure as to why it happens. Other answers on this subject on SO indicate that the nib file might not be connected?

```
DisplayWarningViewController* DWVC = [[DisplayWarningViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DisplayWarningViewController" bundle:nil];
DWVC.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:DWVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: Do your xib file present in project settings -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.   Also check file's owner of the xib file, third tab there class value should be of your class name

Comment: My main.storyboard file is present there and the storyboard has all the xib files, including the one for DisplayWarningViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have view controller defined in storyboard! In that case you should do

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

DisplayWarningViewController *displayWarningVC = (DisplayWarningViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DisplayWarningViewController"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've been scratching my head over this for a while, I didn't even realize that it would be different when I used a storyboard

Comment: @jacks4jokers, Reading the docs can prevent a lot of head scratching. Apple has an extensive and informative document called "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS". You should read it.